# typedef std::runtime_error MyError vs class MyError : public std::runtime_error

Tags: c++, exception, typedef

I'm currently implementing some custom exceptions in a project and can't decide wither to typedef my exceptions or to derived a new class for every exception. Interested in the potential pros and cons of each and if one is preferable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pros in deriving your own class are simple: you can dispatch on it in `catch` handler.

If you decide not to implement your own class, I still doubt you need this typedef: what are you abstracting from? You may as well use plain `std::runtime_error`.

Also you might be interested in [David Abrahams'es](http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html) article about exception handling and implementing your own exception class.

Answer (score 3):

Derive a new class - then you can distinguish in between them. If you typedef, there's no way for the exception handler to know which typedef was used in the throw.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of difficult understanding your question, but if you're making your own custom exceptions I think I would use a derived class in case you want to change the behavior later on.